# How to reroute vehicles in a highway network in sumo?

Tags: sumo

I created a straight highway 6km long and 3 lanes in each way.It consists of number of segments connected to each other and there are almost 200 vehicles in the network . so,I made them to move in circles to keep them until the end of simulation time.
Here is a apart of .rou.xml file:

```
<routes>
  <vType id="normal_car" vClass="passenger" maxSpeed="41.67" speedFactor="0.9" speedDev="0.1" sigma="0.5" />

<route id="route1" edges="e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 e10 e11 e12 e13 e14 e15 e16 e17 e18 e19 e20 e21 e22 e23 e24 e25 e26 e27 e28 e29 e30 e31 e32 e33 e34 e35 e36 e37 e38 e39 e40 e41 e42 e43 e44 e45 e46 e47 e48 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 e10 e11 e12 e13 e14 e15 e16 e17 e18 e19 e20 e21 e22 e23 e24 "/>
```

The problem is at the end of each side of the highway the vehicles have to slow down to cross to the other side one by one as shown in the screenshot below  . Is there a way to make more than one vehicle cross at the same time?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The vehicles slow down to make the movement more realistic. Nobody goes into a turnaround with full speed. I would propose you rather create a circle network (can easily be done with netgenerate, for instance:
`netgenerate --spider --spider-omit-center`)

If you insist on the turnaround then increase the speed on the turnaround inner edge using --junctions.limit-turn-speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can include different vehicle models that vary in properties. This will make them overtake others.